# Run CMD as Administrator in java without password

Tags: java, cmd, admin

I need to run the following command using java:

```
"wmic product where description='" + someProgram + "' uninstall"
```

This CMD works only when running as Administrator.

This program will run **in several machines with different passwords**, so I can't insert passwords in my program.

How can I run it as Admin, without running the whole program as administrator?

**Edit:**

This program runs on a local Windows machine (no dealing with remotes)

Comment: Is the java running on the machine, or connecting via say SSH to the machine?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible in Unix for your Admin to write to write a Shell Script which runs with the priveleges of another User-ID & which members of the Group (or Anyone) may start.

See: Setuid & chmod

Comment: Although the OP doesn't say specifically, pretty sure from use of "CMD" and "wmic" (= "Windows Management Instrumentation Command") that this is on Windows, not Unix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a remote solution (where the Java makes say an SSH connection to the remote and then runs the command), then can't you configure the process running on those machines - providing the SSH server - so it runs commands as an appropriately privileged user?

AND/OR [find a localgroup](https://www.windows-commandline.com/net-localgroup/) that gives the permissions you need?